# How do I prevent GAE database deletion on development server?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

If I don't use GAE development server for several days then it's database vanishes on next launch. Is there any way to prevent it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you run the development server, use the `--datastore_path` option.  This option lets you specify where the database is stored.  (The default location on your system sounds like it is in a temporary folder which is being cleared in between launches - probably when you reboot your machine).